# Why is ASP.NET server control property nothing

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to create a new server control type in ASP.NET. This control would put a RequiredFieldValidator into a certain place. My class inherits from the WebControl class and it has a ControlID property which is the ID of a given control. The RequiredFieldValidator will be generated near the control with the given ControlID. However, the value of ControlID is nothing. In what events can I successfully use this property?

```
Public Class MyControl
    Inherits WebControl

    '...
    Protected Property ControlID As String
    Protected Property IsLinkedBrother As Boolean = False
    '...

    Protected Overrides Sub OnPreRender(e as System.EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnPreRender(e)
        Dim rootControl = If(IsLinkedBrother, Parent, Page)
        Dim controls As Stack(Of Control) = New Stack(Of Control)
        Dim currentControl As Control = Nothing
        controls.Push(rootControl)
        Dim result As Control = Nothing
        While ((result Is Nothing) AndAlso (controls.Count > 0))
            currentControl = controls.Pop
            If ((Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentControl.ID)) AndAlso (currentControl.ID.Equals(ControlID))) Then
                result = currentControl
            Else
                For Each child As System.Web.UI.Control In currentControl.Controls
                    controls.Push(child)
                Next
            End If
        End While
        '...
    End Sub
'...
End Class
```

But ControlID is Nothing for some reason and the event throws an exception. ControlID is never changed after initialization and it is initialized this way:

```
<MyControl runat="server" ID="IDValue" ControlID="ControlIDValue" EnableCliendScript="true" 
    CssClass="Whatever" Display="Dynamic" />
```

I've searched and tried for hours but with no luck. Can anybody tell me what can cause this behavior and why, does anybody has some suggestions for a solution? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ControlID must be public for this to work; it can't be protected and be able to be set from markup.

Comment: Thank you Brian, I'm currently building my project to test this, thank you very much. I'll write about the results as soon as I get them.